# Downgrade java version in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, version, downgrade

I should downgrade my Java version in Eclipse. Indeed, I have Java10 and I should use java7. I am trying to change the settings in "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler" or in the project properties -> Java Compiler, but Eclipse does not underline String.join for example (String.join is available from Java8)

Here are some screenshots:

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler
[image]

Project Properties -> Java Compiler

[image]
Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185205/discussion-on-question-by-picot-downgrade-java-version-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check ***Use '--release' option***, which is exactly for this case.

See:

- [Short video, showing this option](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-ZTkhek5TU&t=296s)
- [Eclipse Photon (4.8) - New and Noteworthy - New `--release` on the Java compiler preference page](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php)